# What is template-bound in polymer?

Tags: polymer, firebase-polymer

I noticed there is a template-bound in firebase polymer `firebase-login.html` after searching polymer documentation cannot find out what is that.

also, any polymer events reference in documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the **event** that fires after the data binding happens in a Polymer's *auto-binding template*.

```
<template id="myTemplate" is="auto-binding">
</template>
<script>
    var template = document.getElementById("myTemplate");
    template.addEventListener('template-bound', function() {
        console.log('ready');
    });
</script>
```

> The auto-binding template inserts the instances it creates immediately
>   after itself in the DOM tree (not in its shadow DOM).
>
> After adding the instances, the auto-binding template fires the
>   template-bound event.

You can read more from [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/databinding-advanced.html#bindingoutside).

Comment: What if we doing this inside `polymer-element` ?  what should be use?

Comment: You don't actually need to do this inside a `polymer-element` because the whole point of having this `auto-binding template` is to enable data binding outside of a `polymer-element`. Within the element, you have data binding support automatically.

Comment: then i think my question is about ` should we make it custom element `?  i will create another question later.