# How to set callback when <template if='...'> is finally instantiated into DOM in Dart Polymer

Tags: templates, dom, dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I have element like that:

```
<polymer-element name="my-app">
  <template>
    <template id="page_template" if="{{authenticated}}">
      <my-page id="page"></my-page>
    </template>
  </template>
  <script src="..."></script>
</polymer-element>
```

I need to perform some initialization when template with id=="page_template" will be actually instanced into DOM.

I've tried to make something like that:

```
authenticatedChange(_) {
  if(authenticated)
    shadowRoot.querySelector('#page').addEventListener(...);
}
```

But got this:

```
Exception: The null object does not have a method 'addEventListener'
```

Looks like 'page' just doesn't exists yet.
Then I tried to put creation event to the end of event-loop:

```
authenticatedChange(_) {
  if(authenticated)
    Timer.run(()=>shadowRoot.querySelector('#page').addEventListener(...));
}
```

This works, but I doubt it is a good style, because there is no guarantee it will actually be created to that step (it's completely implementation-dependent), because no explicit dependency like a Future or callback wasn't binded to event when template is instantiated.

So the question is, does such event exist? All I found was 'template-bound', but this code

```
$['page_template'].on['template-bound'].listen((_)=>print("template-bound!"));
```

being executed in MyApp.created(), generates silence in console.

How to bind my code to instantiate/deinstantiate events?

```
onMutation($['page_template']).asStream().listen((_)=>print("mutated."));
```

Also didn't work for me.

`$['page_template'].shadowRoot` is `null`, so I can't bind to it's mutation at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a mutation observer on your shadow root to do this, add something like the following in your `ready` method:

```
new MutationObserver((changes, _) {
    print(changes.any((record) => record.addedNodes.any(
        (node) => node is Element && node.id == 'page')));
})..observe(this.shadowRoot, childList: true);
```

This will print `true` any time the page is added. The efficiency of this will clearly vary based on how often your shadow dom is changing. Wrap the template in another node and listen on that if you want to get only the local changes.

Comment: That one works, thanks! I'm marking this answer as accepted but during conversation with Günter Zöchbauer I found this way is going to unclear and overcomplicated application design. It's better to wrap all contents of conditional template to new element and then declaratively link it with other ones in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't needed the `template-bound` event myself yet, but it should be the right approach. If `$['page_template']` returns `null` this code might be in the wrong place. `MyApp.created()` is the wrong place for most code, especially wrong for everything that is Polymer related. If you override the `ready()` method and put your code there it should work.

Comment: `$['page_template']` returns correct value in `MyApp.created()`, I said that `$['page_template'].shadowRoot` returns `null`. I've tried to setup callback in ready() and in domReady(), but still see no output in console

Comment: I wrote comment for first time and hit enter too early, sorry. Can you explain when to use `MyApp.created()`, when `ready()` and when `domReady()`?

Comment: Normally you don't use `created` at all. It just has to exist so an instance can be created by the Polymer runtime. You can do some variable initialization or similar but don't use it to access the DOM. I don't remember the difference between ready and domReady. The Polymer.js site has a paragraph about these lifecycle methods. `ready` usually works therefore I never cared about the difference.

Comment: It seems template-bound is only fired by the auto-binding template http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28467712/what-is-template-bound-in-polymer. Why don't you just add the event handler declaratively instead of imperatively?

Comment: From the code in your question it seems you want to listen to an event from the `page` element. You can do that declaratively like `<my-page id="page" on-some-event="{{myEventHandler}}></my-page>` (where `some-event` is the event you want to listen to)

Comment: Ahh I got it. Setting up event handler was only for example, I have much more things to initilize after template instantiated, there is more DOM elements inside that conditional template.

Comment: You could just add a custom element inside the template only for this purpose which fires an event on `ready` or maybe in `attached` (after `super.attached()`)

Comment: I thought about that, but afraid if one fire ready when it's siblings are not yet?  Anyway, it looks too much overcomplicated for task that initially looks simple.

Comment: Most clean solution I see for now would be to wrap all contents of template inside single custom element (like in simplified example I provided), which will have its ready function run just for that, like you  said :)

Comment: Sounds good. I'm not sure if `ready` fires only the first time or every time `authenticated` becomes true but I assume it does. Otherwise you can try `attached`.